# namespaces and rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces, urlhelper

I have a routing like that:

```
  namespace :folio do
    resources :portfolios do
      resources :portfolio_items do
        resources :images
      end
    end
  end
```

Now please don´t flame me because of the deep stacking. This is a mongo db persisted tree like object and those levels are all persisted in the root object.

What puzzles me is the fact that the generated routings read something like

```
folio_portfolio_portfolio_item
```

But when I ask for a url from urlhelper

```
url_for [@portfolio, @portfolio_item]
```

I get a nice exception telling me

```
undefined method `hash_for_folio_portfolio_folio_portfolio_item_path' for #<Module:0x0000000492fc30>
```

See the second "folio" in there? Any idea how I can get rid of that? Providing an :url => is not an option, unfortunately, because that would triplicate my form views and before that I'd rather ditch the namespace altogether. But unwillingly so: this is a rails engine and I would want to avoid clashes.

So, in other words...

I want

```
= form_for [@portfolio, @portfolio_item] do |form|
```

to "just" work :). Is this too much to ask?

**Observation**
a routing like that brings me a bit forward:

```
resources :folio_portfolio_items, :controller=>Folio::PortfolioItemsController do
```

while ugly as hell it generates good urls. Problem is, when I want to to visit one of them I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Folio::Folio):
```

Whatever this means...

As a sidenote I think it is very odd that this happens at all. I think my mapping controllers to domains is the expected one...

**I created a sample app that illustrates this on https://github.com/janlimpens/testroutes**

Comment: why not form_for[@folio,@portfolio,@portfolio_item] ?

Comment: folio is just a namespace (module), not an object. The problem is that urlhelper sees two objects ns::class1 and ns::class2 and generates a ns_class1_ns_class2_path from it, instead of a ns_class1_class2. I could live with that, if I could generate routes that match this...

Comment: regarding @Mauricio - I would like to know if form_for[:folio,@portfolio,@portfolio_item] would make any difference.

Comment: @natedavisolds: this just adds another surplus folio to the mix.